# Does garlic being green automatically mean it will sprout?

Tags: garlic, onions

I purchased some elephant garlic from Walmart after it was beginning to break apart on its own, the center was a spongy consistency, but there hasn't been a shoot from any of the bulbs after a week. Should I just dig it up, and use it, or wait for a few more weeks to see if it will sprout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you purchase seed garlic that was spongy?  If so, take it back and ask for a refund!

Garlic is supposed to be planted when there's a chance for frost.  The cold stimulates bulb formation.  Otherwise you will likely just end up with tiny bulbs and a lot of leaves.

And, if you're planting from garlic that was meant to be eaten, well, you take your chances for reasons that have been discussed many times already here.

Comment: just the stem in the middle was spongy from what I could tell. the grocery store garlic was already sprouting, so I thought it would be good to try walmart garlic next.